# Как кодировка *.java файла влияет на тип char в Java?

Tags: java, char, кодировка

Почему данный фрагмент кода выводит `0`, если кодировка кода в `Windows-1251` и `15` если кодировка `UTF-8`?

```
String s1 = "П";
String s2 = "А";
System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2));
```

В таблице `UTF-8` отсутствует кириллица, а в `Windows-1251` есть все кириллические символы. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: Это шутка да: "В таблице UTF-8 отсутствует кириллица" http://i.voenmeh.ru/kafi5/Kam.loc/inform/UTF-8.htm Зачем бы был нужен unicode

Comment: "0 если кодировка кода в Windows-1251 и 15 если кодировка UTF-8" как это было проверено?

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov Искал в google таблицы, нашел эти http://goo.gl/r0B3e http://goo.gl/EcBD9h.
Судя по вашей таблице 'А' в DEC 208144 в win-1251 192, а диапазон char 0-65535.
Проверял скомпилировав в разных кодировках.

Comment: В java строки и символы всегда UTF, никак такой код 0 не вернёт.
Вот так можете сделать System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2) == 0);

Comment: @VladislavPyatkov я делаю вот так System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2) != 0); Но всегда было false, пока кодировку не поменял. В IDEA по умолчанию Windows-1251 для новых проектов.

Comment: Вообще, String.compareTo сравнивает строки, ориентируясь на Unicode, и исходная кодировка вашего файла тут мало влияет. У меня пример не воспроизводится, в обоих случаях выводит 15. Может, вы неправильно меняете кодировку? Или, может, string остается завязана не ту кодировку, на какую вы рассчитываете?

Answer (score 2):

Проведем эксперимент:

```
public class Cp1251Src {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String s1 = "П";
        String s2 = "А";
        System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2));
    }
}
```

Сохраним файл в кодировке cp1251, попробуем собрать javac 1.8.0_45 с указанием правильной кодировки:

```
>javac -encoding cp1251 Cp1251Src.java

>java Cp1251Src
15
```

15 - правильный ответ, т.к. `String.compareTo` возвращает разность первых отличающихся символов.

Укажем неправильную кодировку:

```
>javac -encoding utf8 Cp1251Src.java
Cp1251Src.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding utf8
                String s1 = "?";
                             ^
Cp1251Src.java:4: error: unmappable character for encoding utf8
                String s2 = "?";
                             ^
2 errors
```

javac отказывается компилировать, т.к. не может преобразовать байты файла в символы, используя указанную кодировку.

IDEA у меня нет, но есть Eclipse. Если в нем указать кодировку файла UTF-8, то вместо "А" и "П" будет виден символ "�" ([U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm), REPLACEMENT CHARACTER). Код успешно скомпилируется, выполнится и выведет 0, т.к. строки теперь равны.

Т.е. там, где javac из-за ошибки преобразования байт в символы отказывается продолжать работу, Eclipse (и, скорее всего, Idea), заменяют непреобразуемые байты на U+FFFD, и работает дальше.

А если файл, сохраненный в кодировке Utf-8 скомпилировать с параметром `-encoding cp1251`, программа выведет 13.

Comment: В IDEA файл изначально был в Windows-1251, при изменении кодировки кириллицу заменило на �. Я заменил все содержимое скопированное ранее до изменения кодировки и получил 15, ранее был 0.

Comment: Видимо IDEA компилирует тот код, который показывает. Если будете собирать проект другими средствами, напр. через ant - будут сюрпризы.

Comment: ant не учил, maven пробовал.
Интересно что System.out.println((int) 'П' + " " + (int) 'А'); выводит "65533 65533" при Win-1251. А System.out.println((char) 65533); "?".

Answer (score 1):

На тип `char` кодировка java-файла не влияет. Компилятор java не может волшебным образом догадаться, какая кодировка у вашего файла. Он использует какую-то кодировку по умолчанию, которую спрашивает у вашей системы. Чтобы всё работало, компилируйте с параметром `javac -encoding utf-8 ...` или `javac -encoding cp1251 ...`, указывая именно ту кодировку, которую вы реально используете.

Comment: Менял кодировку в Intellij IDEA и запускал. Получал 0 и 15 соответственно.

Comment: @Anatoliy Samokisha, согласен после измениния кодировки исходников jar нужно собирать с указанием нужной кодировки.